# Python and MySQL UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Everything is working as it should for the ping tool but MySQL updates are failing.

It should pull the ip address it is currently doing and update it in the MYSQL.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.1.1.151",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="**************",  # your password
                     db="main_system")        # name of the data base
cur = db.cursor()

from threading import Thread
import subprocess
from Queue import Queue

num_threads = 10
queue = Queue()

ips = ["10.1.1.151", "10.1.1.152"]

#wraps system ping command
def pinger(i, q):
    """Pings subnet"""
    while True:
        ip = q.get()
        ret = subprocess.call("ping -i .1 -c 1 -W 50 %s" % ip,
            shell=True,
            stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        if ret == 0:
            cur.execute("UPDATE application_status SET status = 1 WHERE ip_address = %s")
            print "%s: is alive" % ip
        else:
            cur.execute("UPDATE application_status SET status = 0 WHERE ip_address = %s")
            print "%s: did not respond" % ip
        q.task_done()
#Spawn thread pool
for i in range(num_threads):

    worker = Thread(target=pinger, args=(i, queue))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
#Place work in queue
for ip in ips:
    queue.put(ip)
#Wait until worker threads are done to exit    
queue.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that you need to [commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_commit) the transactions, after calling `cur.execute()`.

Hence you'll need to call `db.commit()` after all your transactions are executed.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Alright I made that change and still having issues

ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the binding of the data (ip) to the cursor:

```
if ret == 0:
    cur.execute("UPDATE application_status SET status = 1 WHERE ip_address = %s", (ip,))                
    print "%s: is alive" % ip
else:
    cur.execute("UPDATE application_status SET status = 0 WHERE ip_address = %s", (ip,))
    print "%s: did not respond" % ip
```

Comment: How do I do that? I am new to python

Comment: @StephenM see the code snippet I shared in my answer

Comment: Ohhh I am blind. Thanks for your help :)